# How to properly regex nested strings

Tags: java, regex, match

My program is trying to match strings surrounded by curly braces recursively - i.e when given `{example1 {example2}} {example3} {example4}` it will match `example1 {example2}`, `example3` and `example4`. I tried using `\{.+\}`, but that will match `example1 {example2}} {example3} {example4`. `\{.+?\}` matches `example1 {example2`, `example3` and `example4`. Is there an easy way to do what I want with a regex, or alternatively simply in Java? I am not very well-versed on regular expressions, as you can probably tell.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but it will be an absolute pain to code, since regexes are not meant for this. Just traverse the string and keep track of the number of `{` and `}`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this isn't a duplicate, as I'm trying to extract the strings rather than ensure that brackets are balanced.

Comment: @Keppil, indeed, that's what I ended up doing - it was surprisingly little code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexs aren't good parsing things that require state. 
You could, probably, come up with something that works in some limited scenarios, but not a good regex that could handle a generic case.

You are better off just parsing your string explicitly. Basically, scan the characters one-by-one, and:

- if the char is `{` increase the "nesting counter". If `nesting counter==1`, start a new group, and skip to next char;
- if the char is `}`, decrease the counter. If `nesting_counter == 0`, end the current group, and skip to next char;
- if `nesting_counter>0` append the current char to the group and continue;